# /admin/cms/page/cms/js/change_list.js/ giving a 500 error

Tags: django, django-cms

I am working on getting my first django-cms web site up and running.  I have been following the Introductory Tutorial.  After adding the first page, the system is experiencing an error when trying to display the new page:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cms/js/change_list.js'
"GET /admin/cms/page/cms/js/change_list.js/ HTTP/1.1" 500

Most of the issues I have run into I have been able to search for an answer, but this one is elusive. I am running on OSX with Python 2.7.6, django 1.5.1, and django-cms 2.4.1, and psycopg2 2.5

part of the settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "cms.context_processors.media",
    "sekizai.context_processors.sekizai",
)
```

Any thoughts on the issues?  Might you need more info from me?

Comment: See if this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302149/django-cms-javascript-500-errors) is related to your problem.

Comment: Joseph,  Thank you but it does not.  I already had cms.context_processors.media in my template context processors.